# Passing config variable to Eloquent Models

Tags: php, eloquent

I have a eloquent model with a `photo` atrribute

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class User extends Model {
    public function getPhotoAttribute($value)
    {
        if ($value) {
            return $value;
        } else {
            return $myConfigValue;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I pass that value to the class?

How can I make `User` class aware of `$myConfigValue`?

`$myConfigValue` is an external parameter (it can be located in the database, in another Class, in a separate config file, etc)

Comment: *"in a separate config file"* - If it's with in a file in `config` (the folder in Laravel), you *should* be able to access it via `config("myConfigValue")`. If it's in `.env`, then it's available via `env("myConfigValue")`.

Comment: Ok, I can declare that value as global and i can access it too... I mean, im looking for a way to "inject" that value in the class, not accessing it through a global function or a global/static variable... is there a way?

Comment: Definitely, but that value has to be stored and retrieved somewhere in order to do that, so I'm not sure there would be much point to passing it to the `User` class every time you wanted to use it. For example, `$user = new User($myConfigVariable);` You could have the `__construct()` method "inject" it there, but you'd still need to pull `$myConfigVariable` from somewhere, like `config()` or `env()`

Comment: What i don't want is to inject that value to each instance, i mean, when i do `$user = new User($myConfigVariable)`, because I can get instances directly from database, for example `$users = User::all()` and i want to be able to execute `$user->photo` for each of them and let the accessor do his job.

Comment: Then you'd simply do `return config($myConfigValue);` or `return env($myConfigValue);`... I'm not sure how else to say it :)

Comment: I'm not using laravel, so i cannot use `config` or `env` function, but i can achieve the same with a global variable or something... Im looking for another way to inject that value. Thank you for your time ;)

Comment: Oh; sorry about that. Didn't realize you could use Eloquent without Laravel.